# how to extract overlap from non-dissolved buffer zones in qgis 1.7.4

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have a shapefile with the inventory of all limetree in a region. I made a buffer around each tree.  So, the place where buffers overlap each other is the best place to put beehives.

Is there a way to extract the overlap between non-dissolved buffers in the same layer?  Or is there another way?

Thanks for the help.
Pieter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGis this is not so easy. Since you work with only one table. All the tools I know which perform intersection always need two input tables.

General idea is to intersect all buffers with each other. You can do that easily in PostGIS. Do you have experience?

```
SELECT st_intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom) 
 FROM mytable AS t1, mytable AS t2 
 WHERE t1.gid <> t2.gid AND t1.geom && t2.geom
```

Another approach is to convert the buffers into raster and count the polygons per pixel.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have no experience with PostGIS or Raster calculations.  So I will study on both items and then try out your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QGIS with 
[OpenJUMP](http://openjump.org/) to achieve the result you're looking for.

Here's my related question:

[Extracting Overlapping Parts of Single Polygon Layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172845/extracting-overlapping-parts-of-single-polygon-layer-using-qgis/172875#172875)

Hope this helps.