# How to calculate the area of overlapping buffers within a single layer

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, buffer, area

I am very new to GIS, so don't know if this is EXTREMELY easy or impossible.

I have GPS coordinates for stores (about 15000) for which I have created a buffer zone around each store location obviously (or not) in a single layer. In metropolitan areas I now have overlapping buffer areas. I would like to calculate the area where buffers overlap.

I have established how to do this if each point were a separate layer, but with 15000 points, I just do not have the time or the energy to do this.

Please help.

I am working in QGIS.

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26386/how-to-extract-overlap-from-non-dissolved-buffer-zones-in-qgis-1-7-4/26440#26440

Comment: Is there a specific reason for doing this the vector way or could you work with a heatmap raster?